# Navigation Stack : What Am I missing? Robot not moving?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all, this has been a ongoing battle which I am loosing, the wiki is not the easiest thing to follow.

So I have a robot (2 wheel, running Lidar)

- It runs Hector Slam which gives me /odom
- it can be moved by teleop (nav_msg)

I have created all the files in http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup (move_base running on robot)

I have also setup RVIZ as shown in http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/Using%20rviz%20with%20the%20Navigation%20Stack

However in RVIZ when I press 2D Nav Goal, bugger all happens.
Current errors I seem to be seeing
**No transform between frames /map and /base_link available after 20.003237 seconds of waiting. This warning only prints once**

**[ WARN] [1485103992.288786277]: Timed out waiting for transform from base_link to map to become available before running costmap, tf error: . canTransform returned after 0.101515 timeout was 0.1.**

The problem is I am getting super confused now, going via the Tutorials, things like URDF come up which I dont think I need because of the YAML file?  This like build a tf_broadcaster also appear?

**Theres are my topics : Maybe it does not match the yaml file?

- /cmd_vel
- /initialpose
- /map
- /map_metadata
- /poseupdate
- /rosout
- /rosout_agg
- /rpms
- /scan
- /slam_cloud
- /slam_out_pose
- /syscommand
- /tf
- /tf_static**

I am sure its such a simple thing I am missing!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/252638/navigation-stack-:-what-am-i-missing?--robot-not-moving?/) by [burf2000](https://answers.ros.org/users/28716/burf2000/) on ROS Answers with karma: 202 on 2017-01-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-01-22**:
It looks like you're missing the TF transform between /map and /base_link (TF frames; not topics). It would be helpful to run `rosrun tf view_frames` or `rqt_tf_tree` to look at the TF tree (and post the results here if you can)

**Comment by [burf2000](https://answers.ros.org/users/28716/burf2000/) on 2017-01-23**:
I used files from here https://github.com/DaikiMaekawa/navigation2d_example but not sure what fixed it yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So I found this https://github.com/DaikiMaekawa/navigation2d_example and used their yaml files and edited more launch files and it now works.

---

Originally posted by [burf2000](https://answers.ros.org/users/28716/burf2000/) with karma: 202 on 2017-01-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0